# Can't set mode try in hapijs route and haps-auth-cookie

Tags: hapi.js

I new to Hapijs and I'm having some issues with my route auth configuration.

**Error:**

```
[1] "auth" must be a string
[2] "strageties" is not allowed
```

**Route**

```
exports.register = (server, options, next) => {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
            auth: {
                mode: 'try',
                strageties: ['session'] // or strategy: 'session'
            },
            handler: (request, reply) => {
                return reply.view('partials/index');
            }
        }
    });

    return next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'routes-home'
};
```

**Stragety**

```
    server.auth.strategy(Providers.Session, 'cookie', {
        password: config.server.SECRET,
        redirectTo: '/login',
        isSecure: false
    });
```

Im using happy-auth-cookie and bell. i also have more strategies such as github, twitter... If i setup the auth to just session it work. **auth: 'session'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. I had to provide the mode to my stragety like so:

```
server.auth.strategy(Providers.Session, 'cookie', 'try', { //<= 'try'
    password: config.server.SECRET,
    isSecure: false
});
```

i also had to remove the **redirectTo** property.
Setting the mode at the strategy level provided the functionality i was looking for. Basically, i needed to check is the user was logged in in every route since my navigation menu will change depending on the result. Set the route auth configuration to 'session' for the route that can only be access by logged in users.

Please Refer to: [server.auth.stragety](http://hapijs.com/api#serverauthstrategyname-scheme-mode-options).